# Using python to convert bytearray to float

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, arrays

I'm using python 2.7. Just wonder how to convert bytearray to 2 byte float numbers. The bytearray is:

```
In[13]: temp
Out[13]: `bytearray(b'\xd8[\xda[\xd8[\xda[\xd1[\xe1[\xeb[\xed[\xe7[\xeb[\xe7[\xea[\xd6[\xd5[\xd8[\xd5[\xd4[\xd3[\xe9[\xe2[\xe3[\xe5[\xe6[\xe8[\xdc[\xe6[\xe4[\xe4[\xe8[\xe2[\xd3[\xdb[\xd1[\xda[\xda[\xd7[\xd1[\xd1[\xdf[\xd1[\xd4[\xdd[\xe6[\xdd[\xe3[\xe4[\xdf[\xe1[\xd0[\xd4[\xd7[\xd6[\xd7[\xd4[\xdf[\xdd[\xe0[\xe5[\xe0[\xdf[\xe0[\xdd[\xdd[\xe3[\xdc[\xde[\xd8[\xe0[\xde[\xdf[\xde[\xe2[\xe7[\xe2[\xe2[\xea[\xe1[\xe0[\xda[\xd4[\xd9[\xdb[\xd9[\xdd[\xe1[\xe3[\xe3[\xe2[\xe3[\xe7[\xe1[\xe5[\xe2[\xe8[\xe4[\xe3[')`
```

Want to convert to 96 float numbers in little-endian format, Byte 1 is LSB and Byte 0 is MSB.

Comment: You say little-endian, but then you specify that byte 0 is the most-significant byte, which is big-endian. Could you provide a more precise explanation?

Comment: Your byte string is 14 bytes long. In Python the standard size for a `float` is 4 bytes while a `double` is 8 bytes. Your data doesn't fit a whole number of `float` or `double` numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you need 16 bit precision float?? Like these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` [`fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
import numpy as np

# little-endian
x = np.fromstring(buffer(temp), dtype='<f2')

# big-endian
x = np.fromstring(buffer(temp), dtype='>f2')
```

If you need normal floats, you can convert `np.float16` to floats:

```
# one value
float(x[0])

# all values
[float(a) for a in x]

# see user2357112 comments for other options
```

Comment: If you want to convert a NumPy array to a list of standard Python scalars, the `tolist` method will generally be more robust and more efficient. If you want to convert a NumPy array of half-precision floats to an array of regular double-precision floats, `astype(float)` is the way to go.